# Select if any value in an array is the beginning of a column's value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So I'm given an array `codes` from a Python webserver, and I need to select all rows which have a column that matches to any of these `codes`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.code = a.bcode
WHERE b.code = ANY(codes);
```

But the problem is, these codes might be just *partial* codes, only the beginning of a code. So while a full code is always 5 letters long (they're stored as strings), the array of codes I receive might be something like `['01', '4332', '34443']`. If a row in `b` has `'01233'` as the column's value, it should match to the `'01'` in the array. Notice that it would not match to `'23'`, it should only match to the beginning.

In essential I want something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.code = a.bcode
WHERE b.code LIKE ANY(codes || '%');
```

Obviously appending to array like `codes || '%'` isn't legal, so how could I do this?

Comment: Is it *always* fine to get a partial match or should codes of 5 characters match exactly? Also is the data in these columns text, integers, etc?

Comment: @eurotrash I'm not sure what your first question means. The codes I have stored are 5 characters long, so `'01234%'` is fine as a partial since it will only match to `'01234'`. The data is always as text, everywhere, because leading zeroes do matter (i.e. `04123` vs `41230`, only the latter would partial match to `4123`).

Comment: @eurotrash By "partial" I meant matching to the beginning. So it's not enough that there's somewhere a `'01'` in the code, it has to start with `'01'` (supposing I got `'01'` in the input array)

Comment: `WHERE b.code LIKE ANY(select unnest(codes) || '%');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out how to pass the array into the query.  Obviously, you can construct a `WHERE` clause in Python and do something like:

```
where code like '01%', or
      code like '4332%' or 
      code like '34443%'
```

You can shorten this to a regular expression:

```
where code ~ '^(01|4332|34443)'
```

Or, you could pass it in as a Postgres array, doing something like this:

```
select v.*, p2.pat
from (values ('a'), ('abc'), ('abcd'), ('bacd')) v(x) cross join
     (select array['a', 'b'] as pat) p, lateral
     unnest(p.pat) p2(pat)
where v.x like p2.pat || '%';
```

Using Postgres arrays is particularly useful if you want to return the pattern(s) that match.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this. But the general concept makes sense to me: alter the array to append the `%` character if the length of the item is less than 5.

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...] x
WHERE x.code LIKE ANY(ARRAY(
    SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(u) < 5 THEN u || '%' ELSE u END
    FROM UNNEST([your array]) u)
);
```

Working example:

```
SELECT g
FROM generate_series(9995, 10005) g
WHERE g::TEXT LIKE ANY(ARRAY(
    SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(u) < 5 THEN u || '%' ELSE u END
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['999','10005']) u)
);
```

Result:

```
9995
9996
9997
9998
9999
10005
```

Answer (score 1):

This small function could do the job:

```
create or replace function array_for_like(text[])
returns text[] language sql as $$
    select string_to_array(concat(array_to_string($1, '%,'), '%'), ',')
$$;
```

Example:

```
with my_table(code) as (
values
    ('10001'),
    ('10002'),
    ('20001'),
    ('20002'),
    ('30001')
)

select *
from my_table
where code like any(array_for_like(array['10', '30']))

 code  
-------
 10001
 10002
 30001
(3 rows)
```